# How to convert an array of bytes into an image that can be drawn onto a canvas?

Tags: node.js, drawimage, node-canvas

I'm using `node-canvas` to do some image manipulation (in this example to convert the image to a grayscale version, just to keep the example simple). I have no issues getting the raw data, but I'm having trouble working out how to convert the derived array of data back into something that the canvas context can draw.

```js
import { writeFile } from "fs/promises";
import { loadImage } from "canvas"

import { OUTPUT, WIDTH, HEIGHT } from "../config";

const fadeToGray = ctx => {
  const src = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT).data;
  const dst = new Uint32Array(src.length >> 2);
  
  for (let i = 0; i < src.length; i += 2) {
    dst[i >> 2] = (src[i] * 4899 + src[++i] * 9617 + src[++i] * 1868 + 8192) >> 14;
  }
  
  // I'm stuck here!
  const image = CONVERT_BYTES_TO_IMAGE(dst);

  ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
}

const start = async () => {
  const image = await loadImage('input/test.png');
  const canvas = createCanvas(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
  const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

  fadeToGray(ctx);

  writeFile(`${OUTPUT}/test.png`, canvas.toBuffer("image/png"));
}

start().then(() => {
  console.log('done')
}).catch(err => {
  console.error('dammit', err)
});
```

I feel like I'm missing something very obvious.  How do I convert my array of bytes back into a drawable image?